# ¿Cómo puedo obtener los datos de un GridView con devExpress?

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

Estoy llenando un `GridView` con un método que retorna una tabla 
desde un webservice en ASP.

Lo que quiero es que cuando seleccione una fila especifica me devuelva todos los valores que tiene esa fila y ponerlos en un `TextBox`.

Comment: Por favor mira en la ayuda [ask] , [qué puedo preguntar](/help/on-topic) y [qué no](/help/dont-ask). La pregunta tal cual la tienes ahora es muy amplia y es probable que sea cerrada. Te sugiero que intentes encontrar una solución mediante tutoriales y probando tu código y cuando tengas una pregunta clara lo hagas con [un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo puedes hacer con el evento `RowCellClick` de un `Gridview`:

```
private void gridView1_RowCellClick(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.RowCellClickEventArgs e)
    {
        //Datos visibles en el gridview

        TextBox1.Text = gridView1.GetRowCellValue(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle, "nombre").ToString();
        TextBox2.Text = gridView1.GetRowCellValue(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle, "apellidos").ToString();
        TextBox3.Text = gridView1.GetRowCellValue(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle, "email").ToString();    

        //Si por ejemplo necesitas un dato de una fila que no está visible en el gridview puedes usar lo siguiente:

        DataRow clickedRow = gridView1.GetDataRow(e.RowHandle);
        TextBox4.Text = clickedRow.Item("mensaje").ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

La verdad no especificas si estás usando ASP MVC + C# + DevExpress. En caso de que lo estés haciendo, creo que mi respuesta puede servir.

De una manera u otra, si estás llenando un GridView, vas a necesitar establecer los settings del grid. Hazlo así:

```
    public GridViewSettings GridUsuariosSettings()
    {

        var settings = new GridViewSettings();

        settings.Name = "GridRendPort";
        settings.CallbackRouteValues = new { Controller = "Usuarios", Action = "UsuariossGrid" };

        settings.ClientSideEvents.CustomButtonClick = "function(s, e) {{  CustomButtonClick(s, e); }}";

        settings.CommandColumn.Visible = true;

        settings.KeyFieldName = "CODIGO_USUARIO";

        settings.SettingsPager.Visible = true;
        settings.Settings.ShowGroupPanel = true;
        settings.Settings.ShowFilterRow = true;
        settings.SettingsBehavior.AllowSelectByRowClick = true;

        settings.SettingsAdaptivity.AdaptivityMode = GridViewAdaptivityMode.Off;
        settings.SettingsAdaptivity.AdaptiveColumnPosition = GridViewAdaptiveColumnPosition.Right;
        settings.SettingsAdaptivity.AdaptiveDetailColumnCount = 1;
        settings.SettingsAdaptivity.AllowOnlyOneAdaptiveDetailExpanded = false;
        settings.SettingsAdaptivity.HideDataCellsAtWindowInnerWidth = 0;
        settings.SettingsBehavior.AllowFocusedRow = true;

        settings.Columns.Add("NOMBRES", "Nombres");
        settings.Columns.Add("APELLIDOS", "Apellidos");
        settings.Columns.Add("FECHA_REGISTRO", "Fecha de Registro");

        return settings;
    }
```

Ahora, lo importante en esos settings es:

```
settings.ClientSideEvents.CustomButtonClick = "function(s, e) {{  CustomButtonClick(s, e); }}";
```

La función **CustommButtonClick(s,e);** debe de estar definida en la vista padre de la vista parcial donde se encuentra tu grid.

Y debe de ser más o menos así:

```
    function CustomButtonClick(s, e) {

        var key = s.GetRowKey(e.visibleIndex);

        if (e.buttonID === "btnEditar") {
            s.GetRowValues(e.visibleIndex, 'CODIGO_USUARIO;NOMBRES;APPELLIDOS', OnGetRowValues);
        }
    }

    function OnGetRowValues(values) {
        var CodigoUsuario = parseInt(values[0]);
        var NombreUsuario = values[1];
        var ApellidosUsuario = values[2];

        $("#txtCodigoUsuario").val(CodigoUsuario);
        $("#txtNombreUsuario").val(NombreUsuario);
        $("#txtApellidoUsuario").val(ApellidosUsuario);
    }
```